# Alguien que consiga una forma mas limpia de realizar la salida del siguiente código

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, fórmulas-de-matriz

```js
    tamaño = 13;
    var matriz = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
        matriz[i] = new Array(tamaño);
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            if (j < matriz.length / 2 - 1 - i) {
                matriz[i][j] = NaN;
            } else if (j > matriz.length / 2 + i) {
                matriz[i][j] = NaN;
            } else
                matriz[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
    let incrementalLeft = parseInt(matriz.length / 2);
    let incrementalRigth = parseInt(matriz.length / 2);
    for (let i = matriz.length - 1; i > matriz.length / 2; i--) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            if (j < incrementalLeft) {
                matriz[i][j] = NaN;
            } else if (j > incrementalRigth)
                matriz[i][j] = NaN;
        }
        incrementalLeft--;
        incrementalRigth++;
    }
    console.log(matriz);
```

[image: Salida del Código]

Tengo la siguiente matriz de 13x13 y lo que se requiere es rellenar de NaN los vértices hasta la mitad de la matriz tanto en filas como en columnas cosa de que quede en forma triangular como se ve en la salida de la imagen ... ahora lo siguiente yo lo resolví obviamente con el código adjuntado ... pero incluso a mi me parece rebuscado y feo ... alguien que proporcione algún método mas matemático o algo un poco mas estético

Comment: Esta bastante interesante esta pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lógica de mi programa fue dividir el resultado esperado en 3 partes, la primera parte es el triangulo superior, la segunda, la parte central, es decir donde todos los elementos son 0, y la tercera parte, es el triangulo superior pero al revés.

Por lo tanto solo necesitamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
let tamanio = 13
let mitad = Math.floor(tamanio/2)

let matriz = []
let mitadMatriz = []

for(let i=0; i<mitad; i++) {
    let arrayExtremos = Array(mitad - i).fill(NaN)
    mitadMatriz[i] = arrayExtremos.concat(Array(2*i+1).fill(0).concat(arrayExtremos))
}

matriz.push(...mitadMatriz)
matriz.push(Array(tamanio).fill(0))
matriz.push(...mitadMatriz.reverse())

console.log(matriz);
```

Comment: Genial Me gusto me gusto !!!

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta!